# How to pass just the values of a list as arguments in Java

Tags: java, deserialization, jackson-dataformat-csv

I have a requirement where I need to pass the items of a list as arguments to a library function. This function receives arguments as `String[] args`. So something like `myFunc(list[0], list[1], list[2]...)`. Is there a way to just extract the items of a list and pass them?

Specifics:

Code:

```
CsvSchema schema = csvMapper.typedSchemaFor(PersonDetailsCSVTemplate.class) 
.withHeader() 
.sortedBy("personNameHeader", "personAgeHeader",...) 
.withColumnSeparator(',') 
.withComments();
```

Here the sortedBy function needs multiple strings as arguments based on which it will do the sorting and although I have a list of strings received from csv header row, I am not sure how to pass them individually.

Comment: `list.toArray(new String[0])` converts the `List<String>` into a `String[]`

Comment: 1) Why do you need `String[] args` outside the main method? 2) `myFunc(list[0], list[1], list[2]...` should be the same as `myFunc(list)`

Comment: what is the input type sortedBy(...) method is taking. Var args or comma separated values?

Comment: @AtulKumar [`sortedBy(String... columnNames)`](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-dataformat-csv/javadoc/2.7/com/fasterxml/jackson/dataformat/csv/CsvSchema.html#sortedBy(java.lang.String...)) is a variadic method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can convert your `List<String>` to a `String[]` with the [`toArray(IntFunction<T[]> generator)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Collection.html#toArray(java.util.function.IntFunction)) method that was added in Java 11:

```
String[] strings = list.toArray(String[]::new);
```

Or to pass it directly:

```
CsvSchema schema = csvMapper.typedSchemaFor(PersonDetailsCSVTemplate.class)
    .withHeader()
    .sortedBy(list.toArray(String[]::new))
    .withColumnSeparator(',')
    .withComments();
```

On Java 8, use the overload of `toArray` that takes an array:

```
CsvSchema schema = csvMapper.typedSchemaFor(PersonDetailsCSVTemplate.class)
    .withHeader()
    .sortedBy(list.toArray(new String[list.size()]))
    .withColumnSeparator(',')
    .withComments();
```

Or:

```
CsvSchema schema = csvMapper.typedSchemaFor(PersonDetailsCSVTemplate.class)
    .withHeader()
    .sortedBy(list.toArray(new String[0]))
    .withColumnSeparator(',')
    .withComments();
```

If the array is too small, it will create one of the necessary size, based on the element type of the array you pass in. That is why passing in a zero-length array will work.

Comment: I am using Java 8. This seems to give an error. Does it work in version 8?

Comment: It is not belongs to any jdk version, it just method reference where added in JDK 1.8 if you do not  about method reference than use just old style code. where I showed in the following. @ShubhamGoyal

Comment: @ShubhamGoyal Sorry, that was added after Java 8; for Java 8, you need to use a different override of `toArray`. There are two possibilities. I have edited my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You mean your required function accept only String[] type as argument and you have List of item and you want to pass this list of item function, which you required?If so than you can use List of interface of `toArray();` method For example:

```
List<String> list = Arrays.asList("A", "B", "C");
String[] array = list.toArray(new String[list.size()]);
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));
```

Comment: It's better to use `List.of("A", "B", "C")` if you're on at least Java 9.

Comment: Yes I know but I have using Java 8 ))